# Babylon Text Select

Tags: api, text, hook

How does Babylon recognizing text selection in any software? I have to implement this.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Provided your just using Babylon just for your 3D content and html for your UI, try `window.getSelection()`. You could call this on a `mouseup` event, as you'd expect this to occur at the end of the highlight process.

Something like...

```
const elem = document.getElementById('yourDiv);

let textSelection;

elem.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=> { textSelection = window.getSelection() })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection